# Interpreting Time Profiler in Xcode 7 Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode7, instruments

What does the "546x" etc. mean exactly? Clicking on the (i) icon shows a list of "Heaviest Backtraces", what does this mean in the context of the Time Profiler template? The documentation doesn't shed much light on this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Time Profiler instrument records the call stack 1000 times per second by default. Each recording of the call stack is a sample. The number before x represents the number of samples the Time Profiler instrument recorded. 546x means Instruments recorded 546 samples containing that line of code.